Facebook events parameters not visible in events manager for android app
We are adding meta app events natively inside a flutter app and I am currently working on the android integration, I'm using standard events any they show up in events manager on meta but non of the parameters I added is visible in Event Breakdown nor Sampled Activities tab when I click on view details for any event. I'm using standard events with the recommended params constants, here's a testing sample:
Android code:

According to facebook's logs in my logcat, everything is going well. but whatever I send a params isn't displayed on events manager. any suggestions on what's wrong?
Facebook logs screenshots


Add to cart event

Add to cart selected params

Add to cart breakdown

Add to cart sampled activities

I'm using Facebook android SDK v17.0.0. and we don't use conversions API
The expected result is for the currency and dummy content to be displayed on event breakdown and sampled activities tabs

Having the same issue today - no standard event parameters are showing in the Events Manager section. Sent the issue to FB Ads but doubt I'll receive a reply.
